# shareService in angular 2 - twice subscribe the next function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, rxjs

I have a ShareService in angular 2,and in another component i subscribe that,and this is my code :

```
*******ShareService ***********************************
   private ShopItem$ = new Subject<any>();
ShopItem$_ = this.ShopItem$.asObservable();
public addToCart(item : any){

    this.ShopItem$.next(item);

}

*************in another component**********************

_shareService.ShopItem$_.subscribe((item) => {

        alert("hiii"); <====>this functions execute twice
        this.ADD_TO_CART(item);<====>this functions execute twice

 });
```

my problem is ADD_TO_CART() function execute twice!why?i dont want my cart function execute twice,how to fix this problem??
the ShareService dont have any problem i test it with an function and once execute.

Comment: Do you have more than one instance of "another component" in your application?

Comment: No,and this is first time im have a problem like this!can't fixed it :((

Comment: Either `ShopItem$.next()` is called twice or there are two subscribers.

Comment: No,I check it,Im have a button when user click on the button just ShopItem$.next(item) function execute once...im check all Components but there is no another ShopItem$.next(item)

Comment: Can you add some `console.log(item)` to `addToCart()` to see how often it is called?

Comment: yeap...just execute one time!!!

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Can you reproduce in a Plunker? In plunker editor there is a new button with a template for Angular2 RC.1.

Comment: if i have more than one instance of "another component" the subscriber have problem?

Comment: As @GünterZöchbauer already mentioned, can you please include a plunkr reproducing the behavior? It is more than likely that you have two instances of Component being created and each one would be executing it's own `subscribe` block.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, this is probably due to multiple subscriptions. To verify it is not this, you can put just above your subscriptions, the following line:

```
console.log('pre subscribe, number of observers is: ', _shareService.ShopItem$_.source.observers.length);
```

**Note** this works on rxjs 4, in version 5 you might need a different syntax.

It should give you 0, if you get another value, you have an already active subscription.