# angular 2 subscribe shareService working twice or several times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, rxjs

I have a ShareService in angular 2,

```
******************************shareService*************************
import { BehaviorSubject , Subject}    from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class shareService {


    isLogin$:BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    CheckUser = this.isLogin$.asObservable();
    public isLogin (bool){
        this.isLogin$.next(bool);
    }
}
```

and its my another component and `subscibe` the `CheckUser`;

```
***********************another Component*******************************

        _shareService.CheckUser.subscribe((val) =>{
            *********all of this scope execute for several times just i have one another component and one next function*******
            this.isLogin = val;
            alert(val);
            if(this.isLogin){

                console.log("req req req");
                this.MyBasket();

            }
            else if(this.ext.CheckLocalStorage("ShopItems")){

                    this.ShopItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ShopItems"));
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        _shareService.sendShopItems(this.ShopItems);
                    },100);

            }

        });
```

my problem is i execute once  `this.isLogin$.next(bool)` but subscribe function execute twice or several times !!!! my basket function is an xhr request this means when user loged in i get the several request to server!!!i cant fix it...i dont know this problem is for angular 2 or not,Anyone have this problem??
last a few days i Involved in this problem!

Comment: Same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654458/shareservice-in-angular-2-twice-subscribe-the-next-function. Please provide a Plunker to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `shareService` is getting multiple instances.

One of the solutions is forcing the service to be a singleton.

Something like this should work:

```
import { provide, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class shareService {
  private static instance: shareService = null;

  // Return the instance of the service
  public static getInstance(/*Constructor args*/): shareService {
    if (shareService.instance === null) {
       shareService.instance = new shareService(/*Constructor args*/);
    }
    return shareService.instance;
  }

  constructor(/*Constructor args*/) {}
}

export const SHARE_SERVICE_PROVIDER = [
  provide(shareService, {
    deps: [/*Constructor args dependencies*/],
    useFactory: (/*Constructor args*/): shareService => {
      return shareService.getInstance(/*Constructor args*/);
    }
  })
];
```

Everything that is required on your current constructor should be placed where it says `constructor args`

Now on your components you use the service like this:

```
@Component({
  providers: [SHARE_SERVICE_PROVIDER]
})
```

And then you can call it like you usually do.

Another solution would be injecting your current service on the main component of the app. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198785/how-do-i-create-a-singleton-service-in-angular-2) for more info.

Comment: i import import {SHARE_SERVICE_PROVIDER} from "./shareService"; but when call _shareService. CheckUser.subscribe,i get error Checkuser is not defined!plz help me how to use it

Comment: did you add the `constructor(_shareService: shareService)` ?

Comment: absolutely yes...
i have a shopService and give data from shareService...my shopService is injectable() and import to 3 component...i test it with push a alert in `constructor(){ alert() }`, the alert function 3 time execute...and my 
` _shareService.CheckUser.subscribe()` function Too 3times execute...this means my constructor function execute number of import the own service...how to fix it?? i want just one time execute :(

Comment: and what arguments does your `shareService` constructor have?

Comment: nothing!!is empty i dont need to anything in my shareService

Comment: Create a plnkr reproducing the issue. Else is almost impossible to figure out the full problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the service is singleton and the component subscribe to it each time it created or (I don't see the full code) at the point the

```
_shareService.CheckUser.subscribe
```

is placed , so CheckUser should be a method that returns an Observable . if you have plunkr I can edit it . 
Another semantic problem is that the observable should end with $ and not the BehaviorSubject.